# New ceiling light works does not work

Tags: wiring

I have an old ceiling rose configuration and tried connecting a new chandelier 5 bulb style light but it keeps tripping the mains when I try to turn it on.
The electrician I first had out said there was a fault with the new light so I got a new one.  Same thing.
I've put the ceiling rose configuration back and it works fine with a single bulb but not with the new light.

1. [image: List item]

Comment: "*New ceiling light works does not work*"  I need help with that one.

Answer (score 1):

Your new light probably has insufficient terminals and you're connecting wires which should not be connected, causing a dead short.

You need a **4-terminal** ceiling rose or connection block: live (red, or brown); neutral (black, or blue); switched live (black with red marker); and earth (bare, sleeved green-yellow).

The earths should all go in the brass terminal to the top left - I can't see where they connect at all, they **must not** be left unconnected and pushed up into the ceiling - and the lives should be in the middle terminal marked Loop, not in a separate terminal.

[image: Internal wiring of UK 4-terminal ceiling rose]

http://wiki.diyfaq.org.uk/index.php/House_Wiring_for_Beginners#Lighting

Comment: Thank you I will try that.

Comment: The earth was pushed up into ceiling by the electrician :/  eeek!  I had earthed my light when I tried it but he didnt